# Android Listview and switch

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm confused with ArrayAdapter. I have a listview, composed of subviews.

Each subview contains one txtview and one switch.

Right now, i'm able to print out all the list with my items but i have 2 problems :

- When i switch on a switch, if i scroll down and come back, switch's off.
- I don't know how to get all the switchs. Indeed, i'd like to be able to switch on ALL the switchs at the same time.

Here's what i have :

```
public class PersAjoutOpAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txt_pers;
        public Switch switch_pers;
    }

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private boolean tous_coches = false;
    private ImageView img_check_all_pers_op;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> v_switchs;
    private boolean en_train_de_checker_all;

    public PersAjoutOpAdapter(Context p_context, ImageView p_img_check_all_pers_op) {
        super(p_context, R.layout.item_pers_ajout_op, Friendly_Account.projet_actu.getPers_dans_projet());

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(p_context);
        img_check_all_pers_op = p_img_check_all_pers_op;

        v_switchs = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Friendly_Account.projet_actu.getPers_dans_projet().size());

        for (int i=0 ; i<Friendly_Account.projet_actu.getPers_dans_projet().size() ; i++) {
            v_switchs.add(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pers_ajout_op, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_pers = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_pers_ajout_op_prenom_nom);
            holder.switch_pers = (Switch) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_pers_ajout_op_switch);
            rowView.setTag(holder);

            holder.switch_pers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                }
            });

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        Personne pers = Friendly_Account.projet_actu.getPers_dans_projet().get(position);

        holder.txt_pers.setText(pers.getPrenom());

        holder.switch_pers.setChecked(v_switchs.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }
```

Can you help me with those 2 points ?

Thanks.

Comment: list view recycles views. You need a way to maintain the state

Comment: Ok, i thought to make an arrayList of booleans to "save" the state of each. Is it a good approach or is there a better way ?

Comment: use a sparse boolean array. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

Comment: I nearly get it, thanks. When there's a switch i need to save the state into the sparse boolean (right ?). How can i do that ? In the getview i have a `setOnCheckedChangeListener`but i cannot know the position of the switch no ?

Comment: the same concept that works for checkbox should work for switch as well. follow romain guys solution